# I want to capture a specific colum from a command output using python 3

Tags: python, text-processing

On an ubuntu machine I want to capture the second column of the output of the command "dpkg -l" . I use python 3 and want to use the subprocess module. the following command:

```
fh=open("/tmp/test.out", 'wb')
with subprocess.Popen(["dpkg", "-l"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
   fh.write(proc.stdout.read())
```

returns as under:

```
ii yum 3.4.3-3 all Advanced front-end for rpm  
ii zeitgeist-core 1.0-0ubuntu4 amd64 event logging framework - engine  
ii zenity 3.24.0-1 amd64 Display graphical dialog boxes from shell scripts  
ii zenity-common 3.24.0-1 all Display graphical dialog boxes from shell scripts   
ii zip 3.0-11build1 amd64 Archiver for .zip files  
ii zita-ajbridge 0.7.0-1 amd64 alsa to jack bridge  
ii zita-at1 0.6.0-1 amd64 JACK autotuner  
ii zita-lrx 0.1.0-3 amd64 Command line jack application providing crossover filters  
ii zita-mu1 0.2.2-2 amd64 organise stereo monitoring for Jack Audio Connection Kit  
.....  
.....
```

I want to get the second column, example:

```
....  
....  
yum  
zeitgeist-core  
zenity  
zenity-common  
zip  
....  
.... etc etc
```

Please help

```
>>> with subprocess.Popen(["dpkg", "-l"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
...     line1=proc.stdout.read()
...     type(line1)
...
<class 'bytes'>
```

the type is bytes. How to split. When i use the following:

```
>>> with subprocess.Popen(["dpkg", "-l"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
...     line1=proc.stdout.read()
...     line2=str(line)  # the type is byte so I try to convert to string
...     print(line2)
...
10
```

(The output is messed up)

Comment: Not sure why this would be off-topic. This is just another text processing question, like we accept all the time. The fact that it asks for a python solution is no different from asking for awk, sed or whatever language.

Comment: @JacobVlijm so it would be perfectly fine if I posted an awk solution without any Python at all?

Comment: @muru absolutely, it is not an answer for op only. We see this kind of question "using this or that" all the time, even if the language sn't fit to do the job.

Comment: @JacobVlijm it may not be, but OP's insistence on submodule means that using pipes (or any shell construct) would mean that answer is useless for them.

Comment: @muru I guess OP just wants the file, but even if he specifically wants python' s subprocess, it is a plain user case.

Comment: Your last code chunk has an obvious typo. You wrote `str(line)` instead of `str(line1)`. Was it intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way to get the output of system calls is quite outdated. Use

```
subprocess.check_output()
```

instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

f = "/home/jacob/Desktop/output.txt"

lines = subprocess.check_output(["dpkg", "-l"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
with open(f, "wt") as out:
    for l in lines:
        if l.startswith("ii"):
            out.write(l.split()[1] + "\n")
```

Replace `f` with the actual path of the output file.

Output file:

```
...
...
apg
app-install-data
app-install-data-partner
apparmor
apport
apport-gtk
apport-retrace
apport-symptoms
appstream
apt
apt-transport-https
...
...
```

#### Note

The solution above will create a file, ending with an empty line. If that is an issue somehow, use the solution below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

f = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad/output.txt"

lines = subprocess.check_output(["dpkg", "-l"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
open(f, "wt").write(
    "\n".join([l.split()[1] for l in lines if l.startswith("ii")])
)
```

Comment: This does exactly what I needed. Awesome and elegant. Thanks.

Comment: @RaviOpenSource Great! You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that `dpkg -l` is essentially a frontend to `dpkg-query`, and `dpkg-query` allows you to format the output. From [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html):

```
dpkg-query actions
  See dpkg-query(1) for more information about the following actions.

  -l, --list package-name-pattern...
      List packages matching given pattern.
```

And [`man dpkg-query`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg-query.1.html):

```
-l, --list [package-name-pattern...]
      List  packages  matching  given  pattern.
-W, --show [package-name-pattern...]
      Just like the --list option this will list all packages matching
      the  given  pattern.  However the output can be customized using
      the --showformat option.
```

So instead of `dpkg -l`, do:

```
dpkg-query -f '${Package}\n' -W
```

`'${Package}'` is **not** a shell variable here. It's a format specifier for `dpkg-query`.

Answer (score 0):

```
words=line1.split(" ")
print(words[1])
```

words is then a list of strings and words[1] is the one you want.